# remove with deep recursion in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How can I implement the remove function with deep recursion?

I know how to write remove in shallow recursion, but it's hard to change this into deep recursion.

```
 (myremove '(1 2) '(1 ((1 2) 3) (4 (5 ((1 2) 5))))) -> (1 (3) (4 (5 (5))))
```

Comment: it would help to see what you have written so far

Answer (score 2):

I suppose by "deep recursion" you're referring to recursion over a tree instead of recursion over a list?

The more low-level answer to this is to recurse down both the car and the cdr of the cons cells, instead of just the cdr. Though I'ld prefer to use higher order functions, in this case calling mapcar recursively:

```
(defun myremove (item tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      tree
      (mapcar (lambda (subtree) (myremove item subtree))
              (remove item tree :test #'equal))))
```

EDIT: Here's a low-level solution:

```
(defun myremove (item tree)
  (cond ((atom tree)
         tree)
        ((equal item (car tree))
         (myremove item (cdr tree)))
        ('otherwise
         (cons (myremove item (car tree))
               (myremove item (cdr tree))))))
```

Comment: how can i write this program in low level? i didn't study tree part yet

Comment: @Jen: See the EDIT to my answer. Basically it's the same like a recursion over a list, you only need to recurse both into the car and the cdr, and cons the results together in the recurse case.